# Height for Table View Cell calculating as zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, heightforrowatindexpath

I have `UITableViewCell`s that the **height of my cell is calculating to be zero for some reason.**

Here's what I currently have:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {
        ListTableViewCell *cellOne = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cellOne) {
            cellOne = [[ListTableViewCell alloc] init];

            FR *fD = (FR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];
            NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.link];

            cellOne.labelHeadline.text = title;
            cellOne.labelDescription.text = description;
            cellOne.labelPublished.text = dateString;
        }

        // Make sure the cell's frame is updated
        [cellOne setNeedsLayout];
        [cellOne layoutIfNeeded];

        CGFloat heightOne = [cellOne.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return heightOne + 2;

    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[D self]]) {

    // more code
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {

        FR *fD = (FR *)model;

        ListTableViewCell  *1Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell"];

        if (!1Cell) {
            1Cell = [[ListTableViewCell alloc] init];

            FR *fD = (FR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];

            1Cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
            1Cell.labelDescription.text = description;
            1Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;

        }

        return 1Cell;

    }

    // more code
}
```

**I'm not sure why `heightOne` is returning zero** when I breakpoint to see what value `heightOne` is.

*I'm using AutoLayout.*

Any ideas?  Thanks!  Will post extra code if needed, thanks!

Comment: Why are you setting cell variables in this method? That should be done in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Also have you checked to see if cellOne is not nil?

Comment: Yeah I'm doing it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` too, I guess I can take it out of here.  And yes, `cellOne` is not nil.

Comment: When I try your code I got a recursive call stack exception at `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. Could you past your `cellForRow` method code? And how you register your cell in your table view?

Comment: @sunkehappy sure, I added the code to the original question, thanks!